# Error sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a table in my `sql server 2008` database

```
COMMENT(idcom,content,username);
```

This table has 2 records which `username` = `lecturer`

Now I want to delete all comments which have username= lecturer:

First, I test the query in SQL Server:

`DELETE FROM COMMENT WHERE USERNAME='lecturer'` -> it works fine: 2 records were deleted.

Then I applied that query in my c# code :

```
public bool delete(string userdeleted)
{
    string sql="DELETE FROM COMMENT WHERE USERNAME="+userdeleted; //userdeleted= lecturer
    try
     {
               SqlConnection sqlconnection = new SqlConnection();
                SqlCommand sqlcommand = new SqlCommand();
                sqlconnection.ConnectionString = connstring;
                sqlconnection.Open();
                sqlcommand.Connection = sqlconnection;
                sqlcommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                sqlcommand.CommandText = sql;
                sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sqlconnection.Close();
                sqlcommand.Dispose();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
}
```

When I built that code, program jump inside `catch` statement and return false???.

Try to debug, it has an error: `$exception:{"Invalid column name 'lecturer'."}` at line `sqlcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Help!!! Why the code doesnt work even it works fine in SQL SERVER???

Comment: Consider a `using` for the `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` objects.  ie, `using (var sqlConnection = new ...)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suspect the value of `userdeleted` is just `lecturer` rather than `'lecturer'`. Therefore your SQL statement is:

```
DELETE FROM COMMENT WHERE USERNAME=lecturer
```

That's the immediate problem - it's looking for a column called `lecturer`. If you use that SQL in SQL Server Studio (or wherever you were testing before) you'll get the same error.

However, you *shouldn't* just add quotes - you should use parameterized SQL:

```
string sql="DELETE FROM COMMENT WHERE USERNAME=@username";
...

sqlcommand.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = userdeleted;
```

Parameterized SQL is important in a number of ways:

- It helps to prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- It keeps the SQL clearer (you don't end up with a load of concatenation, and fixing up quoting issues like this)
- It avoids conversion issues, particularly for date/time values

Comment: Haha, got in there before me. +1 my friend!